# How do I make Linux Mint stop pestering me for passwords all the time?

Tags: linux-mint, screen-lock, lock

I run Linux Mint in a VM.

Every single time I look at it, it has gone into some sort of "lock screen"-like state where it requires me to enter a password to get back. This is very annoying.

How do I turn this off entirely so that it never "auto-locks"? I already looked through a bunch of a settings but found nothing.

Also, I already tried this and it does ***NOT*** work! https://vitux.com/how-to-disable-enable-automatic-screen-lock-in-linux-mint-20-trough-cli/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which Desktop Environment you're using. There could be multiple places for these lock settings.

Look for **screensaver settings**, there may be a lock screen/session option. It's not uncommon to have multiple screensaver applications installed so you may have to look at all of them to figure out which is active.

Also look in the **Power Manager settings**. This is another place that there could be a lock setting under Display, Session, or Screen.